# Sublime Text 3 print function autocompletion

Tags: python, printf, sublimetext3

I switched to Sublime Text 3 the other day and got this annoying autocomplete problem.

Whenever I type `print(` it autocompletes to: `print(value, ...)`. The ellipsis is totally expendable and I have to manually remove the dots every time.

Do you know how to change this behavious?

Comment: How about you stop offtoping? :)

Comment: This is not it but thanks.

Comment: @sshashank124 **all** of your comments to this question are off-topic and subjective. Assume that changing the code editor is not an option.

Comment: what plugins do you have installed?

Comment: You nailed it! Jedi - Python autocompletion was causing it. Thx